# What's happening internally in the Scheduler and/or Batchable in my situation?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a scheduled job that runs every night at midnight. It updates around 7000 records without entering any data into the records directly. About 150 records don't update as expected.

If I simply call update (or Database.update()) on these records as individual records or in a list, in an anonymous Apex block, they update as expected. When I call the batch that the scheduler calls in anonymous Apex they don't work.

The Batchable class (as well as the Schedulable class) literally has the smallest amount of code you could imagine:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM XXX ]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<XXX> scopePolicy){
        Database.update(scopePolicy, false);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
```

Scheduler:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        try{
            XXX xxx = new XXX();
            database.executebatch(xxx, 15);
        }
        catch (DmlException e)  {}
    }
```

Does Batchable use a separate API?

Is it possible for the Scheduler or Batchable classes to create settings that are slightly different than if the records are updated directly?

The User that runs the Scheduled job is the same User that I have been debugging with.

Answer (score 0):

*(too long for a comment)*

1. After nightly run does LastModifiedDate change on these 150? Maybe they update OK but something comes and resets them to original value (maybe you have some parent-child relations on this object and there's some cascade/rollup at play).
2. What field do you expect to see updated, can you put field history tracking on it. With any luck you'll see it changing state A to B and something setting it back to A.
3. Does the batch `implements Database.Stateful`?
4. If you run it with raw `update` statement, not the `Database` version - do you see any errors in Setup -> Apex Jobs
5. Is the amount of executions roughly ok? 7000 / 15 = 467 batches processed or are you ~10 batches short?

Comment: 1. No 2. I will try that 3. No 4. I will check that 5. I will check that

Comment: 4. There is an internal SF.com error. This is on an old version of SF, like 8 years ago.

Comment: There's no such thing as old version, SF updates everybody 3 times/ year. Your code in there might be old and benefit from recompiling with newer API version though. Hard to say, you could try raising a ticket with SF support, they may suggest some field indexing. Always same records die? Anything special about them like > 10K child records?

Comment: like the API version is 31. Always same records.

Comment: try raising a case, they'll be able to match the weird number ("GACK") to their logs. You could try reducing the batch size bit more, recompiling with higher API version... Do you know how to capture a debug log? This batch might look like a stupid update but it probably triggers some side effects to run (trigger, flow, workflow, process builder...) - debug log could help pinpointing exact line where the problem is.